# NdefRecord.createMime bug in arguments

Tags: java, android, nfc, mime-types, ndef

I have a method that writes data to a discovered NFC tag (the data comes from an array of records `toWriteRecordsList`).

```
// ... more up here ...
for (String record : toWriteRecordsList) {
     String[] recordArr = record.split(":");
     // I verified the recordArr contained the correct data
            try {
                // This line writes 'text/plain' as the message/payload
                //records[currentRecord] = NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", recordArr[1].getBytes("US-ASCII"));
                // This line works as intended...¯\_(ツ)_/¯
                records[currentRecord] = NdefRecord.createMime(recordArr[1], "text/plain".getBytes());
            } catch (Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            currentRecord++;
        }
// ... actual writing down here ...
```

Bizarrely, when I use the `NdefRecord.createMime` method as the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html#createMime(java.lang.String,%20byte[])) specify then the encoded message, when displayed in the Android default Tag app ("tag collector"), is whatever the first argument is (in this case the message the phone prints is "text/plain"!)

When `createMime()` definitely has this signature:

`public static NdefRecord createMime (String mimeType, byte[] mimeData)`

Because this seemed so bizarre to me, I swapped the arguments (including calling `.getBytes()` to satisfy the prototype) and it worked! I tried this on two different devices (Galaxy Nexus and Galaxy S4) and got the same behaviour.

I can't find any record of the Android bug so I figured I'm doing something wrong. What the hell is going on?

Comment: The method worked as intended on all devices I tested. How do you read the data from the tag?

Comment: @MichaelRoland:   `Tag detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);`

Comment: That's not reading any tag *data*.

Comment: Sorry I must have misunderstood. Do you mean how am I reading the data once it's been encoded? If so, by just detecting it through the default Android "tag collector" thing.

Comment: Okay, so what makes you believe that the (Android default) Tag app would display the content of a MIME type record? Since this app does not invest any effort in decoding the MIME type, it simply displays the type name of the MIME type. Hence, the method `createMime()` works as expected/documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the `NdefRecord.createMime(...)` method. The Android default "Tag" app displays MIME type records by showing the name of the MIME type and not its payload. Hence, the app correctly shows the first argument of the `createMime()` method (i.e. the type name).

Showing the payload of the MIME type record would require the Tag app to decode the record payload based on the type name, which this app simply does not do. See the source code of the `getView()` method for MIME records in the Tag app: [MimeRecord.java:59](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Tag/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/src/com/android/apps/tag/record/MimeRecord.java#59).

Note that if you would want the Tag app to display text stored inside an NDEF record, you would use the NFC Forum Text record type:

```
NdefRecord r = NdefRecord.createTextRecord("en", recordArr[1]);
```

Or for Android before API level 21:

```
public static NdefRecord createTextRecord(String language, String text) {
    byte[] languageBytes;
    byte[] textBytes;
    try {
        languageBytes = language.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        textBytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(ex);
    }

    byte[] recordPayload = new byte[1 + (languageBytes.length & 0x03F) + textBytes.length];

    recordPayload[0] = (byte)(languageBytes.length & 0x03F);
    System.arraycopy(languageBytes, 0, recordPayload, 1, languageBytes.length & 0x03F);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, recordPayload, 1 + (languageBytes.length & 0x03F), textBytes.length);

    return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, null, recordPayload);
}

NdefRecord r = createTextRecord("en", recordArr[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately the method createTextRecord is not available to me (as it is API 21). Is there another workaround?

Comment: Thank you. Note for API < 19 you must use `Charset.forName()` and not `StandardCharsets`. All working now.